# How to assign value to a local variable in function in DataWeave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

[image]Hi i am getting an error saying Invalid input ' ', expected '}' for the do block. I am trying to create a concatenated String output

```
fun getStreetAddress(address1 ,address2) = 
do {
var addr1 = address1
var addr2 = address2
var finalAddress = ""
---
if(null != address1 and sizeOf(address1>30)) 
addr1 = address1[0 to 30]
if(null != address2 and sizeOf(address2>30)) 
addr2 = address2[0 to 30]
finalAddress = "$(addr1) $(addr2)"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using variables incorrectly. You can't assign a value to variable in the body of the block. Only in the definition part, before the `---` separator. Remember that DataWeave is a functional language, not an imperative one.

Try returning the result of the scores directly. You can also use if() as a function.

Comment: Sorry , i am not following 100% . Would you able to make the code change to make it running .

Comment: I'm not I'm front of a computer jus a phone, I can't test it. It should be something like   `---(if (cond1) address1[0 to 30] else "" ) ++ (if (cond2) ...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can expand it all out and not use variables at all with something like

```
    fun getStreetAddress(address1 ,address2) = 
    (if(sizeOf(address1 default "") >30) 
        address1[0 to 30]
        else address1) 
    ++ " " ++ 
    (if(sizeOf(address2 default "") >30) 
        address2[0 to 30]
        else address2)
---

getStreetAddress("asdf","1234567890123456789012345678901234567890")
```

If you really are wanting to assign variables inside your function you can break up the logic a bit. The important thing to remember is everything below the --- is the return statement for the function.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
     fun getStreetAddress(address1,address2) = do{
        var add1 = (if(sizeOf(address1 default "") >10) 
            address1[0 to 10]
            else address1) default ""

        var add2 = (if(sizeOf(address2 default "") >10) 
            address2[0 to 10]
            else address2) default ""
        ---
        add1 ++ " " ++ add2 
        }
---
    
getStreetAddress("1234567890123",null)
```